# Excel convert decimal to date time

Tags: excel, datetime, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert these numbers `in seconds` to a date-time format `yyyy-mm-dd`at a specific start date for example 2014-01-01.I tried searching for some online resources for this task, however, I was unable to find anything.

For example, at `T = 86400`, I would like it to be converted to `2014-01-02`. When `T=129600`, then it would be 1.5 days from 2014-01-01 so it should be converted to `2014-01-02`.

Any help is appreciated. And I apologize if my syntax is incorrect as this is my first time using stackoverflow.

```
T  
86400  
129600  
172800  
259200  
345600  
432000  
518400  
523800  
532542.8571  
542828.5714  
555685.7143  
580242.8571  
592521.4286  
604800  
629357.1429  
660278.5714  
691200  
734400  
756000  
777600  
783000  
786375  
793125  
800625  
815625
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=$A$1+A2/60/60/24
```

[image]

Comment: Is A1 a date number? as in 01.01.2014?

Comment: @matt yes, it is real date formatted as ```dd.MM.yyyy```. Result is formatted as ```yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss```.